# gem - v or gem install bundler giving error rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Currently on my system i have installed `rbenv` and `rvm` both. when i do `which ruby` it gave me this `/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rbenv/shims/ruby` and on `which rails` it gave me `/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rbenv/shims/rails`.

but on doing `gem install bundler` it installs the gem but with an error

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
```

as its showing that its going for `.rvm/gems` as per `which ruby` and `which rails` , its going in `.rbenv/shims`

even on doing gem -v its giving me this

```
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.2/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/home/ijunaidfarooq/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.7/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- gem-wrappers (LoadError)
2.4.5
```

application is working totally fine on localhost but when i update some gems and deploy on `awselasticbeanstalk` , it gives me error which is

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: most simple solve is leave something one or `rvm` or `rbenv`

Comment: if i try to remove `rvm` then it will delete all `.rvm` and then will application use `rbenv` for gems?

Comment: rvm you can remove in next way `rvm implode`, than from `home/.bash_profile` remove `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` if you use linux...

Comment: can you run `which gem`?